# Hanging SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm updating a table at work and SQL Yog has been hung for over 30 minutes. I didn't want to hit CTRL-ALT-DELETE and terminate the task because I wasn't sure if it would somehow mess up production if I kill the query before it's done?

This is what I ran:

```
USE prodWNG
UPDATE customerItemEntry
SET orderType = 12;
WHERE customerNumber = 546339;
```

[edit: ok you got me, this was a joke - but honestly, I've seen this happen. It also doesn't seem to matter how much experience a person has. I've seen team leads hose production by running a bad query such as the one above, it really can strike anyone, anywhere. So, thanks for the fun responses, but this is a good reminder for us all to be careful!]

Comment: uh oh, something isn't right here...

Comment: I feel for you, I mess stuff up sometimes too. If you can't rollback, I hope you've got a good plain backup. Generating update queries from it or reloading would be simple enough. The updating assumes that no side effects of updating orderType happened during the original update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out.

```
USE prodWNG;
UPDATE customerItemEntry
SET orderType = 12
WHERE customerNumber = 546339;
```

Note the placement of the semi-colons. Since you put it before the condition, you'd update the entire table's orderType to 12 if the query were to be successfully ran. (hopefully you were in a transaction?)

Kill the query if you can, if successful, you've updated the whole table.

Answer (score 3):

yes - kill it, you will need to do a rollback anyhow.

you have updated all records to type 12;